# placing views in workbench

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I wanted to design my views when my RCP application is stared.
That means for `viewA` has to be appeared left side,on below `viewB`.Then in the editor area space I wanted to add another `ViewC` and bottom of editor area `ViewD` and right hand side `viewE`,below `ViewF`. How do I design? Not able to attach the image here!!
Any link is there placing the views on workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to this, you must do away with the editor area, as you cannot have a view inside the editor area.

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);

    layout.addView("viewA", IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, layout.getEditorArea());
    layout.addView("viewC", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.666f, "viewA");
    layout.addView("viewE", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.5f, "viewC");

    layout.addView("viewB", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.5f, "viewA");
    layout.addView("viewD", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.5f, "viewC");
    layout.addView("viewF", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.5f, "viewE");
}
```

Please note that the sequence of statements matters..

Comment: Thanks Tonny. When do we want to use Folders? Becuase I saw in our mail rcp template, they have used folders for placing the view.

Comment: Typically I use just the `perspectiveExtensions` extension point to layout my perspectives, and there you have no need for folders. When using `createInitialLayout`, use a folder when you want to place multiple views in the same folder/stack. Otherwise, there are no need for it.